# Error during Cross-compiling C code with Dynamic libraries

Tags: android, c, arm, cross-compiling, codesourcery

I've two files:

lib.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void hi() {
  printf("Hi i'm a library function in lib.so\n");
}
```

and main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dlfcn.h>
/* based on Jeff Scudder's code */
int main() {
  void *SharedObjectFile;
  void (*hi)();

  // Load the shared libary;
  SharedObjectFile = dlopen("./lib.so", RTLD_LAZY);

  // Obtain the address of a function in the shared library.
  ciao = dlsym(SharedObjectFile, "hi");

  // Use the dynamically loaded function.
  (*hi)();

  dlclose(SharedObjectFile);
}
```

And I've tried to build an executables using the following commands:

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`
>
> gcc -c -fpic lib.c
>
> gcc -shared -lc -o lib.so lib.o
>
> gcc main.c -ldl

And it works pretty well.
Then I've tried to export my program on Android (Nexus One, with ARM-v7-0a arch) using the following commands:

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`
>
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -c -fpic lib.c
>
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -shared -lc -o lib.so lib.o
>
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc main.c -ldl -o main
>
> adb push main /system/app

The result of executing ./main on the correct folder on my smartphone is just:

> ./main: not found

even if my file is right there!

Am I missing anything during the cross-compile process? Any help?
I'm using the cross-compiler from CodeSourcery and it works well for static programs without .so libraries.
Thanks

***EDIT***: as Igor states below, that was a linker issue. This command fixes it:

> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o test main.c -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker -ldl

in my very case I need other libraries because in /system/lib/ there are no many .so files.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not using the NDK?

Comment: Does C code, once executed on android device, fail to find the .so in its folder? I knew programs should check in same folder, /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib for .so library files but I've none of the latter two on my device

Comment: How about adding error checks and `dlerror` calls to `main`?

Comment: @Michael: I can't use NDK, I should achieve the execution of such code with a single cross-compiler call using command line.

Comment: Since `"./lib.so"` contains a slash, `dlopen` should just try that filename, and all the stuff about `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and /usr/lib should not apply.

Comment: Where are you pushing the .so file to?

Comment: I've inserted dlerror calls but still having

./main: not found

the .so is in the same folder of the main executable because of the explaination given by aschepler

Comment: Maybe there's trouble finding `libdl.so`, rather than `lib.so`...

Comment: maybe you're right aschepler, it should be a problem with Android linker (I've tried with a simplier HelloWorld program but still getting <not found>). I'm now trying to figure out if there's a way to edit linker's path in order to make all the things work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "not found" message refers not to the shared object but to the dynamic linker. Linux uses `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` (or `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` for x64) while Android uses  `/bin/linker`. You can check which dynamic loader your program uses with `readelf -l`, e.g.:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000034 0x08048034 0x08048034 0x00100 0x00100 R E 0x4
  INTERP         0x000134 0x08048134 0x08048134 0x00013 0x00013 R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]
```

You can specify a linker to use with ld's `--dynamic-linker` switch, but there are likely to be other differences. For example, Android uses a stripped-down libc implementation called bionic, and it may be missing functionality that your program relies on, or have different behavior.

You should use NDK or another Android-targeted toolchain when compiling programs for Android. Even though it's based on Linux kernel, the differences are large enough that Linux-targeted toolchains are not sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Igor! That's the explanation I was looking for. My issue is with linker indeed since if I use readelf -l on my main, it says "/lib/ld-linux...." and so it's a wrong linker. I'm finding many more threads dealing with this problem now that I know it's a linking matter. I just need to properly use arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld and I hope it will be done.