# Error while Running NodeJs on ARMv7 IMX6Q Board, How to fix it?

Tags: node.js, embedded, armv7

**What I Want** : I want to run nodejs on ARMv7 freescale imx6q board with no internet but network connectivity.

**What I did**  : I took pre built binary from nodejs official download. extracted them and tried to run node binary. But it throws error "No such file or directory". I have tried changing permissions also. Have a look at logs below.

```
mx6q:/node/node-v5.9.0-linux-armv7l/bin# ls
node  npm
mx6q:/node/node-v5.9.0-linux-armv7l/bin# ./node
bash: ./node: No such file or directory
mx6q:/node/node-v5.9.0-linux-armv7l/bin# ls -l
total 22084
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      22612411 Jan  1 03:37 node
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            38 Jan  1 01:04 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
mx6q:/node/node-v5.9.0-linux-armv7l/bin# cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 10 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 1988.29
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpd32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x2
CPU part        : 0xc09
CPU revision    : 10

processor       : 1
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 10 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 1988.29
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpd32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x2
CPU part        : 0xc09
CPU revision    : 10

processor       : 2
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 10 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 1988.29
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpd32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x2
CPU part        : 0xc09
CPU revision    : 10

processor       : 3
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 10 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 1988.29
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpd32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x2
CPU part        : 0xc09
CPU revision    : 10

Hardware        : Freescale i.MX6 Quad/DualLite (Device Tree)
Revision        : 63012
Serial          : d4111f0ec91719d8
mx6q:/node/node-v5.9.0-linux-armv7l/bin# file node
node: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=e7c667ffc2519bf31b963b29954863c673be6fba, not stripped
mx6q:/node/node-v5.9.0-linux-armv7l/bin#
```

Anybody who has worked on the same or have any lead, How to overcome this error ?

Comment: It's dynamically linked, so do you have all the right libraries present?

Comment: It is in the same folder structure as nodejs tar had provided. I did not do anything special.

Comment: So you could well be missing some system library it depends on - what does `ldd` have to say?

Comment: ldd says "not a dynamic executable" :(

Comment: Hmm, might be the loader itself - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14939101/3156750

Comment: Could be, But I can't see where is it looking ? They must have have put linking in relative path, So this file-tree should work. Anyway I guess, I will need to cross-compile by myself in such case.

Comment: OK, I just checked and it apparently wants `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3`.

Comment: Okay this could be the actual problem. My file system uses /lib/ld-linux.so for linking and ld-linux-armhf.so.3 is not available.

Comment: Thanks @Notlikethat , That only was problem. I compiled with a none hf compiler and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  @Notlikethat suggested, Pre-built binary was looking for /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 and was not available.

Compiling source code in my own environment worked fine.